# To Enable right click in disabled control

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have a textbox which is disabled and has value .And i want to enable right click option to copy the disabled value from textbox (Windows application).Pls help me to do this.

Comment: What I will usually do when I have a similar need, is enable the `TextBox` and just change it to `ReadOnly` instead of disabled... This will allow you to copy/paste the value, but without changing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, keeping in mind that you have to have your contextmenustrip added:

```
private void YourFormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ContextMenu mnu = new ContextMenu();
     MenuItem mnuCopy = new MenuItem("Copy");
     mnuCopy.Click += (sen, ev) =>
     { 
         System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(YourTextBoxName.Text);
     };
     mnu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { mnuCopy });
     YourTextBoxName.ContextMenu = mnu;
}

private void YourFormName_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctl = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
    if (ctl != null && !ctl.Enabled && ctl.ContextMenu != null)
    ctl.ContextMenu.Show(this, e.Location);
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this works for getting the text from a `Button`. A `TextBox` shouldn't be much different.

Comment: How to copy this value and paste it in another textbox in another form

Comment: But When i click it Copy option is not displaying

Comment: The above code works, I've tested it myself. Whey you say click copy option, what do you mean it's not displaying. You should see the copy context menu, if you click it, the text is copied to the clip board of your pc and then you can paste the text where ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a disabled element in a page, the event is handled by the parent element of the disabled element.
for example if your textbox is in a page then the page handles it. if the text box is in a different container like div, then that container will handle the mouse click event.
for your situation, you could write a handler on the parent element.
a javascript function that will catch the event and it can read the value for you. for instance, the JS function can change the disabled property to false, read the value, and then disable the textbox again.

Comment: Why are you mentioning JavaScript when the question is tagged C# and Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to Vijaya's answer, I handled the problem by just placing the control with `Dock=Fill` into a panel control with zero padding and margin. So you would do your things in the MouseUp event of the panel instead.